# Area under surface between two curves

Tags: matlab, plot, area, surface

I want to determine the area between the red line and the blue line but only to the y-value of 4.559. How can I achieve that?

[image: Curve]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the code you have to draw these lines.

Comment: It is unclear where you want to start the integration, what does the red line stands for?

Comment: @EBH We better discuss this in the optimized post --> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421441/area-between-line-and-curve-no-function?noredirect=1#comment64255660_38421441)

Answer (score 1):

**In general:**

- First you have to subtract the two functions from each other.  After
  that, you have a function that represents the delta in y for each
  point on the x-axis.
- After that you have to calculate the integral, for matlab you should look here [Matlab - Numerical Integral](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)
- The last step is inserting the left, and the right bound of your desired area to calculate. The result is the area under the surface

**Be careful when subtracting the functions, the result of the area might be negative (negate it in this case) if the "bigger" function is the subtrahend**

Comment: Does this work even if I do not have the function given explicitly?

Comment: In this case you should look at this question [MATLAB: integrate shade area under curve(no function)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305609/matlab-integrate-and-shade-area-under-curve-no-function?rq=1) 

You could also try this [Integration of Numeric Data](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/integration-of-numeric-data.html)

Can you edit your querstion adding more information for those two function definitions? (example pointdata eg.)