# Area between line and curve (no function)

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, area, curve

I want to calculate the area beween the orange and the blue line. I managed to shade the area. But I do not know how to apply the `trapz` function in order to get the area. In this post: [Area under surface between two curves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409981) I got some solutions but I do not have a specific equation for the curves just the plots per se.

The code for the orange line is:

```
x_1 = [0,M1_1];
y_1 = [c1,c1];
v = plot(x_1,y_1,'LineWidth',2)
```

The blue curve is a plot of arrays with the length of (10000x1)-abscissa and (1x10000)-ordinate.

If I use

```
%c0_1: Intersection blue curve with y-axis
%c1_1: Intersection orange curve with y-axis
A = trapz(ab1(0:c1_1),ab_y1(c1_1:c0_1))
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as
>   index  Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when
>   used as index  Error using trapz (line 58) LENGTH(X) must equal the
>   length of Y in dim 2.

How can I apply my `trapz` function easily on my problem?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Area under surface between two curves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409981/area-under-surface-between-two-curves)

Comment: Yes I modified the plot in order to give a better understanding of my problem. If I modify the old question, will people see it?

Comment: Yes, people can see it because it will bump the question to the top of the *active* list on the homepage. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313528/does-the-question-will-be-bumped-to-top-of-queue-when-it-get-edited) Meta post and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) page in the [help] where is written: "*Editing a post also bumps the question to the top of the homepage. [...]*". Note that asking the same question twice is discouraged and mostly not well-received by the community.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Matt ! Sorry for that. Will keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: If the blue line is asymptotic as x->0 then you will get area = infinity, unless you bound it also from the top.

Comment: Hi @EBH it is bounded but you cannot see it. I actually got the intersection point of the blue curve with the y-axis in my workspace, so that is fine :-) Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer, although I'm not sure what is the difference between the situation here and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420623/shade-and-calculate-specific-area), and therefore I'm not sure it truelly answers your question...

Anyway, you don't need to know `y1` function explicitly, just to have its' series of data.

```
x = 0:0.1:12;       % x data
y1 = 3*exp(-0.5*x); % y data
y2 = 0.5;
lineStart = find(x>=0,1);
lineEnd = find(y1<=y2,1);
f = plot(x,y1,'b',x,ones(1,length(x))*y2,'r','LineWidth',2);
ylim([0 4])
hold on
area(x(lineStart:lineEnd),y1(lineStart:lineEnd), y2,...
    'EdgeColor', 'none', 'FaceColor', [0.5 0.5 1],'ShowBaseLine','off')
hold off
A = trapz(x(lineStart:lineEnd),y1(lineStart:lineEnd));
```

I added also the illustration of the integrated area:
[image: Integrating between y1 and y2]

Tell me is that solves the problem ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! I saw that I failed to set up the conditions of the intersection properly! Now it is very obvious, especially thanks to your code! Much appreciated mate! :)

Comment: The units of your `y` axis, since you integrate over `x`.

Comment: One last question. I tried to get the same results for the function but just turned. https://s31.postimg.org/mc3ym1omz/Zwischenablage01.jpg
But I got an error or better to say StartLine and EndLine are both 1 in the Workspace. Do you know what mistake I might have made? Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: The code `lineEnd = find(y1<=y2,1)` assumes that `y1` starts above `y2`, and  so it's finding the first intersect of them. If `y2` already starts above `y1` then you get `lineEnd = 1` as a result, and the length to integrate on is `0` - this is why you get the error.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. I tried to modify the lines so that `lineStart = find(x<=100,1);` (because 100 is the max x-value in my case) and `lineEnd = find(y1>=y2,1);` and I think that is the mistake. But logically I just tell Matlab to find where y1 is bigger than y2. But unfortunately it does not work. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: @MatlabNewb this is becoming to messy, and I find it hard to follow your final goal. I suggest that you'll edit your question or write another one to meet your needs in a more general way (i.e. you have more than one function),  and then it is possible to write a script that preform what you need.

Specifically to what you wrote, I think you swapped `lineStart` and `lineEnd`.